# Como utilizar EF Core Code First no Azure Synapse

Tags: sql, entity-framework, microsoft-azure, entity-framework-core

Estou tentando utilizar migrações para gerenciar esquemas de banco de dados com o Entity Framework Core e C# no Azure Synapse, quando executo o comando update-database recebo uma mensagem de erro conforme descrito abaixo:

```
Enforced unique constraints are not supported. To create an unenforced unique constraint you must include the NOT ENFORCED syntax as part of your statement.
```

Esse erro ocorre pelo fato do Azure Synapse não aceitar o uso de PRIMARY KEY sem que a mesma esteja acompanhada por NONCLUSTERED e NOT ENFORCED. O script abaixo funciona perfeitamente quando executado no msqlms:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.sample_table
(
    c1 int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    c2 char(10) NULL,
    c3 datetime NULL
)

ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_t1_c1 PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (c1) NOT ENFORCED
```

Para incluir NONCLUSTERED pelo mapeamento do EF basta apenas definir IsClustered(false) conforme exemplo abiaxo.

```
public class ManifestationMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Manifestation>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Manifestation> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Manifestation");

        builder.HasKey(prop => prop.Id)
           .IsClustered(false); // Include NONCLUSTERED 
        ...
```

Não encontrei nenhuma solução para incluir pelo EF o NOT ENFORCED.

Obs: Não tenho esse problema quando estou utilizando o Azure SQL Server, nem quando utilizo Sql Server instalado localmente, apenas no Azure Synapse (Sql Server DW).